# php script for break connections

Tags: php

how can i break the connection of  user to internet used php script......
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Connection Handling!

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php

```
if(connection_status() == 1 || connection_status == 2) // Timeout or Abort
{
   //Skip the DB shizzle
}else
{
   $DB->inserter->user('john','doe','password');
}
```

Comment: ...interesting. Thanks for the reference. But note that it only comes into play if `ignore_user_abort` is enabled, and that it's just for polling the status, not changing it.

Comment: why would you want to change the status if the user has disconnected, theres no point in forcing content out if the user is no longer connected!

Answer (score 0):

And why the ruby tag? :)

Php is a server-side language, if you need to perform client-side actions you need to use a client-side language. Javascript or VBScript to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `exit()`? This will stop script execution. The server will finish up the response, and the connection will be closed.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php